# How to add more items to a list in Elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I don't know any ELisp, but I need to configure the list of languages to use evaluate source code blocks inline using Org-Babel.

Using this [site](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html), I was able to get Python source-code blocks executed. However, I would now like to add support for other languages like C, C++, Matlab and others.

I know I must add identifiers as mentioned on [this](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html) site to the variable `org-babel-load-languages`. How do I add the extra elements to 
this list?

Currently I am setting the variable `org-babel-load-languages` via, 
this code in my `.spacemacs` file

```
  (org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   '((python . t)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enabled languages is a list `(...)` where each list item looks something like `(python . t)`

So you could extend your current code like so:

```el
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((python . t)
   (c . t)
   (cpp . t)
   (matlab . t)))
```

I'm using something like this to generate the same result:

```el
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(org-babel-do-load-languages
    'org-babel-load-languages
    (mapcar (lambda (lang) (cons lang t))
            '(python c cpp matlab))))
```